# How to restore Windows XP menu entry in GRUB?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I'm using Lubuntu with WinXP in dual boot for several weeks. Today I've ran update and GRUB now does not show WinXP menu entry in GRUB.

sudo update-grub didn't found Windows.

/boot/grub/menu.lst - no such file.

Comment: From the terminal run: sudo os-prober , this is the script used by grub to detect OSes, if it's failing to find windows it may show you some error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Lubuntu 10.10, you need to install os-prober with

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

and then update grub again with

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hmm, still did not work

Answer (score 7):

[This site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) should give you everything you need.

Btw, if you are on Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10 you won't see a /boot/grub/menu.lst, because that's not what grub uses anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

menuentry "Windows XP " {
   set root='(hdX,X)'
   chainloader +1
}

in boot/grub/grub.cfg to section

#### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom

#### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom

(hdX,X) - drive with windows xp

SAMPLE:

`### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

menuentry "Windows XP " {

set root='(hdX,X)'

chainloader +1

}

#### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###`

[Maybe help to You :) Look for 13 post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1200513&page=2)

UPD1: [Full Illustrated Guide for grub2](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html)

UPD2:[image: That's I mean]

UPD3: [Some configs for grub.cfg](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Configuration%20File%20Commands.html)

Comment: Editing `grub.cfg` will only work until the next kernel update (or update of anything else that causes `update-grub` to be run), because `update-grub` will overwrite that file based on its configuration files & scripts.  One of these scripts runs `os-prober` and should find WinXP, if not StalkerNOVA needs to find out why (see João's question).

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: Granted the answer may be wrong, but if you are that sure, add some detail as to why.  All you are doing is leaving the questioner in doubt.

Comment: 1) Yes, This work only until next kernel update. This is non hard to re -add this 4 lines into grub.cfg again

Comment: 2) This method work for me. Because my win7 don't recognized by grub anyway. Only when i manually add this lines to grub.cfg (Please Explain why my answer is wrong? You have the same situation ?O_o)

Comment: @litvin05 Thanks a lot, your answer was helpful. I tried using update-grub and os-prober but  it didn't work.