# Vista missing from grub bootlist after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on a logical partition a while ago. When I get to the grub bootlist, Vista is not there. What i get is this:

```
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-26
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-26 (Recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-25
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-26 (Recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-24
Ubuntu, with linux 2.6.32-26 (Recovery mode)
Memory test (memtest86+)
Windows vista (loader) (on/dev/sda1)
windows recovery environment (loader) (on/dev/sda2)
```

"Windows vista (loader)" is an acer erecovery manager

Im guessing that grub installed on my primary partition so it overwrite the vista MBR and i dont have the option to boot vista. Is there some way i can just edit the MBR and add vista to it or how will i have to repair this?

here is my boot script http://pastebin.com/7HZFjBT7

Comment: Similar Question: How to restore Windows (XP) menu entry in GRUB? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/11916/how-to-restore-windows-xp-menu-entry-in-grub

Comment: have you tested both entries?

Comment: i already have os-prober installed but it hasnt worked.it only found

/dev/sda1:Windows Vista (loader):Windows:chain and
/dev/sda2:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain

Comment: I can help you if you post the output of bootscript http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: here is the bootscript http://pastebin.com/7HZFjBT7

Comment: The output of update-grub suggests that it is able to see Vista.Bootscript output contains Vista under OS-prober.How come it not be listed in Grub menu..?Are you sure it is not listed on your grub bootlist?

Comment: Please run update-grub once more and post the output    `sudo update-grub`

Comment: the only two vista things in the grub menu is windows vista (loader) which boots into the acer eRecovery manager which has 3 options: restore to factory settings, restore to restore point and exit. the first two are greyed out. exit is all i can choose.

the second is windows recovery environment which boots into a basic System recovery program.

Comment: Just run update-grub once more and post the output of `sudo update-grub` let me sort out this problem.

Comment: here ya go. same as before http://pastebin.com/Cij8ujT6

Comment: The last two line says that it can find those entries,                                                                                                            `Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1`               
`Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda2`

Comment: yes those two are available on the grub menu. it says it in my original post but neither boot into vista

Comment: Post this output `sudo cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wafGPcr0

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot/snap of Grub menu?

Comment: here is a photo http://imgur.com/1a6tC.jpg

Comment: Obviously os-prober does not "see" any Vista partitions other than that for recovery. Likewise we all have not clue on what partition your Vista resides. Check for a file `BOOTMGR` on any NTFS partition. This file tells grub/os-prober that there is Vista present (`NTLDR` would be for XP or NT).

Comment: it says there is bootmgr in the first two partitions in the bootscript from ealier. it seems vista is installed on sda2 because winload.exe is on that.

Comment: @tacomesa: grub is able to boot to /sda2 (last entry!). It says it is "windows recovery environment" and thus maybe your (broken?) Vista. What errors do you get if you boot there? If you cannot boot at all then have a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10410/windows-7-doesnt-boot-after-ubuntu-install/10418#10418

Comment: LOL I can find vista in your snapshot.What else you need??

Comment: Boot Ubuntu and purge Grub packages.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge grub grub-pc grub-common`

Then reinstall,

`sudo apt-get install grub-common grub-pc`

Follow the on-screen instructions, choose your proper device i.e, sda in your case and then,

`sudo update-grub`

Lets see how that goes.

Comment: @karthick87: as has been said, /sda1 is Acer Vista recovery partition intended to restore factory settings - that means most likely wiping Ubuntu ;). Note that at the moment even this does not work for tacomensa. Odd: /sda2 says it's some recovery also even though it has boot flag. /sda4 is Acer/XENIX stuff. What's left is /sda5, a data partition named "Data". IMO no need to reinstall grub as it already is there on /sda.

Comment: think im just going to reinstall both windows and ubuntu. ive been putting off a fresh start for a long time. guess now is the time to do it. thanks for the help

Comment: @tacomensa: that would also be a chance to make clear and clean partitions on your disk ;)

Comment: Wait a second. I think I found the problem from your comments. You said it boots to a recovery environment from the second one. That is completely normal, and that is your vista installation right there. If you follow the instructions you can boot again. Just don't do anything to wipe ubuntu. I've boot to that a couple of times before.

Answer (score 3):

According to your boot info script output you only have two bootable Windows partitions, and both are included in your grub.cfg. Have you tried selecting the "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on/dev/sda2)" option? That may be your main installation, just mislabeled for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and tried the 2nd option, the Vista loaded right up and worked fine.
They're flipped on the grub bootlist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: nope. it hasnt added anything else to the bootlist