# Grub 2, Windows Vista, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, windows

This is how it was for years: I had Windows Vista working fine on one hard drive. I had an older Ubuntu working on another hard drive. I was able to select which hard drive to boot.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB drive with the intention of it being a completely fresh, overwrite it all, new install on the Ubuntu hdd. It worked. It wrecked my Windows Vista mbr too.

I cannot figure out how to make the Windows Vista drive boot. How do I do it?

[Ubuntu boot selector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0xuG.jpg)

[Bootinfo Results.txt](http://pastebin.com/PVbEEabg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/16663/vista-missing-from-grub-bootlist-after-installing-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: I read through that entry. I did as much as I could with it. I added an image of Ubuntu's boot selector and bootinfo results.txt to this question.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub` in a terminal?

Comment: This must be a newer computer as you have installed Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Was Windows on sdb, as that is now a gpt partitioned drive also. Windows only boots from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives with BIOS and only from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. And UEFI and BIOS are not compatible. You do not show any Windows install, just the boot loader files in sda1. I would install a Windows boot loader into sda, but without the Windows install partition it still will not boot.  It also looks like you used Windows to create gpt partitioning on sdb, as that has the Microsoft reserved partition.

Comment: sdb is a storage only drive, which was formatted months or years ago with Windows Vista. I can still see, access, move everything on sda and sdb as if nothing happened. Everything is there except a way to boot Windows Vista. I guess this is an archive everything and reinstall Windows ordeal. I should figure out and do an Ubuntu installation in mbr mode instead of Uefi mode if I want both hdd's in the same computer, right?