# I messed up university computer

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I'm using university PC which is Lenovo that came with Windows 8. I want to install Ubuntu to it. I've backed the data up, made extended partition, and installed Ubuntu. I have done this before to other PC and it went good. But not this time. This time after I installed it, Grub was not detecting Windows 8, so I tried to use Boot Repair. It didn't work. I've tried everything, but it just doesn't work. Boot Repair always showed different error prompt.

Can I just start over by installing new Ubuntu? Will that work?
To make clear: I don't know what UEFI is, is that relevant to the installation process (I installed Ubuntu by old fashioned way, same with Windows 7)?

Please help...

Comment: Are you trying to get it to boot to Windows 8 again? Or to get a dual-boot menu to pick Ubuntu or Windows? Does Ubuntu boot ok now?

Comment: I still want to dual boot. At this point I'm too afraid to restart, it's using USB Ubuntu now but I'm guessing Grub already deleted.

Comment: This is a much more complete answer than I could write: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported . It includes troubleshooting for failed installations.

Comment: @cremefraiche I'm reading that currently. So, I can just start installing Ubuntu all over again the proper way without messing the system?

Comment: Follow the part of troubleshooting that suggests re-installing Ubuntu on the partition you have designated for it.

Comment: You'd might as well see if Ubuntu is already installed correctly, what happens on reboot (without the USB booting first)?

Comment: I think the lesson to be learned here is, not to mess with other people's property... If you really want to use ubuntu at school, you should buy a laptop, use a LIVE cd or access your home computer by remote desktop.

Comment: @Xen2050 grub was running and entering rescue mode. I will try reinstalling properly right now. Hopefully nothing is broken. (my friend has same problem a while ago and she had to change motherboard ugh)

Comment: Ok... a "correct" install should fix grub too. And don't forget the bigger lesson - If it's the University's computer you should be able to bring it back to the University's help/IT guys and ask them to fix it :-)

Comment: Yep, thanks all. @PeterRaeves message received, sir

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to run `update-grub` from within Ubuntu, and may need to install/check `os-prober`

See this A. for a little more info, and an option to manually edit the grub.cfg config file https://askubuntu.com/a/12127/129271

- After reading updated comments, it sounds like Ubuntu may not be installed correctly after all, so this may not apply...

Comment: Already tried that but it has error 'couldnt found canonical /cow' or something