# Windows not showing in Ubuntu Bootloader

Tags: boot, server, bootloader

I initially had the following components on 5 partitions on my pc:
sda1 Windows Xp
sda5 Windows 7
sda6 Data
sda7 Data2
sda9 UbuntuDesktop
The ubuntu bootloader would show up at start and would give me the following options:
UbuntuDesktop
Windows 7 bootloader
The windows 7 bootloader would allow me to fire up either Windows 7 or Windows XP.
So, all was working fine.

---

Now, I no longer needed windows xp and I wanted to install UbuntuServer. So, i deleted the sda1 partition and remade it and installed UbuntuServer on it. When prompted to include UbuntuServer in the bootloader, i selected no (as it was telling me to select yes only if it had detected all my OSs, but it had detected only UbuntuDesktop and not Windows 7).
After finishing the installation, I restarted the PC.
The bootloader now showed the following:
Ubuntu
Windows 7 bootloader
(It wasn't showing anything named server)
(idk if the server option, named something else, was showing up)

Since I couldn't find the Server option, I loaded into UbuntuDesktop and tried to repair the grub using Boot Repair.

After restart, the bootloader shows the following:
Ubuntu
Ubuntu 16.04 (The UbuntuServer)

I have lost my Windows bootloader and cannot boot into Windows!!
Please help!!

Here is the file that is generated after I repaired using BootRepair:

[Link to text file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DyNUk9_hzTFA7qLTPU84LWQvqqxC2ogA?usp=sharing)

PS: I even tried os-prober and the grub-update, but still windows was not detected.

Comment: Windows only boots from one NTFS primary partition with the boot flag. Since Windows XP was first install, it was your boot partition. And then your Windows 7 install updated the sda1 partition with its boot files bootmgr & BCD. If you erased sda1 before copying boot files & boot flag to another primary NTFS partition you will not boot Windows. Windows 7 in a logical partition is not directly bootable using Windows and then not repairable  with Windows tools. With some partitioning tools you may be able to convert sda5 to sda3 and then repair Windows.http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Comment: any other way of restoring windows apart from reinstalling? Any way in which I can tweak the ubuntu bootloader??

Comment: My quick advice is DUAL BOOT is a mess and can mess up your entire system.  Its best to have a clean install and not to dual boot.  However, you maybe can copy some of your data to a flash drive or a free internet drive.  Be very carful!  Windows is not required these days to work on serious work.  :)  Are you having stability problems with windows?  You maybe just need to clean up your drives a bit.

Comment: Did you try converting your Windows 7 from logical to primary partition with fixparts? Then you have to add boot flag and then run Windows repairs to add bootmgr & BCD files that are missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore Windows XP menu entry in GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11916/how-to-restore-windows-xp-menu-entry-in-grub) and [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)